# Is there a way of comparing two dictionaries using the values of the keys?

Tags: python

I am working on two dictionaries. The first dictionary "Blacklist" contains addresses as key and dates as values. The second dictionary "transferred" also contains addresses as key and  dates as values. I want to compare the two dictionaries to check if any of the "transferred" address is in the "blacklist" address. if there is a match, i want to check if the date on the blacklist was before or after the transferred date. I want it to create a new dictionary "update" with address as key and value to be "before" or "after" as the case may be.

Please take note "94.142.136.0/21" matches "94.142.136.190"

```
blacklist = {'93.118.36.235': '25/02/2016', '62.149.128.160': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.163': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.166': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.72': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.74': '05/06/2017', '69.163.171.33': '10/03/2014', '69.163.200.61': '22/12/2014', '94.142.136.190': '19/02/2016'}

transferred ={'94.142.136.0/21': '28/06/2019', '185.2.4.0/22': '01/07/2019', '213.158.64.0/19': '01/07/2019', '5.154.240.0/24': '01/07/2019', '78.159.140.0/22': '01/07/2019', '81.88.48.0/20': '01/07/2019'}

found = {}

for k,v in blacklist.items():
     for k1,v1 in transferred.items():
         if k1 = k:
            if v1 > v:
               found.append(k1, 'before')
            else:
               found.append(k1, 'after')
```

I expect this as the result

```
found = {'94.142.136.0/21': 'before'}
```

Comment: You essentially need a way to get Ip address from ip domain and subnet mask, don't you?

Comment: yes i want to get ip address from the ip domain and subnet mask then find if the address was before or after the blacklist data

Comment: what if it's the same date?

Comment: It should be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check if the IP address in the `blacklist` dictionary is in one of the CIDR blocks in the `transferred` dictionary. Then you need to convert those date strings to `datetime` objects so you can compare them

```
from ipaddress import ip_address, ip_network
from datetime import date

blacklist = {'93.118.36.235': '25/02/2016', '62.149.128.160': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.163': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.166': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.72': '05/06/2017', '62.149.128.74': '05/06/2017', '69.163.171.33': '10/03/2014', '69.163.200.61': '22/12/2014', '94.142.136.190': '19/02/2016'}

transferred ={'94.142.136.0/21': '28/06/2019', '185.2.4.0/22': '01/07/2019', '213.158.64.0/19': '01/07/2019', '5.154.240.0/24': '01/07/2019', '78.159.140.0/22': '01/07/2019', '81.88.48.0/20': '01/07/2019'}

found = {}

for ip_addr in blacklist:
    for cidr_block in transferred:
        if ip_address(ip_addr) in ip_network(cidr_block):
            blacklist_date = date(*map(int,blacklist[ip_addr].split("/")[::-1]))
            transferred_date = date(*map(int,transferred[cidr_block].split("/")[::-1]))

            if transferred_date > blacklist_date:
                found[cidr_block] =  'before'
            else:
                found[cidr_block] =  'after'

print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these methods to convert the formats, check if they are equal.

```py
import socket,struct

def makeMask(n):
    "return a mask of n bits as a long integer"
    return (2L<<n-1) - 1

def dottedQuadToNum(ip):#Pass just 94.142.136.190
    "convert decimal dotted quad string to long integer"
    return struct.unpack('L',socket.inet_aton(ip))[0]

def networkMask(ip,bits):#Pass 94.142.136.0 and 21
    "Convert a network address to a long integer" 
    return dottedQuadToNum(ip) & makeMask(bits)
```

Answer (score 0):

the ipaddress module seems to do what you want:
[]https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

```
from ipaddress import ip_network, ip_address

found = {}
for k,v in blacklist.items():
    for k1,v1 in transferred.items():
        if ip_address(k) in ip_network(k1):
            found[k1] = 'before' if v1 > v else 'after'
```

Comment: This didn't convert the date so your program could not check which was greater